# Android getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) returns path to /storage/emulated/0 instead of pictures path

Tags: android

I would like to create a directory in the main Pictures directory. I can't get the proper pictures directory to return, I can only get /storage/emulated/0

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
+ myFolderName;
```

Permission is present:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: if you are looking for memory card path you wont get it on all devices. As per official documentation `public static String  DIRECTORY_PICTURES  Standard directory in which to place pictures that are available to the user.` you cannot control what path is returned

Comment: then how can i return the path of the pictures directory? other apps on my phone seem to be able to find it